# how to know the id of the previously inserted sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, forms, session-variables

why would this increment $orderid by 2 at each time? how should this be solved?

### inserting client info from form

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'db_connect.php';

$orderdate = date("Y/m/d");
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$address = $_POST['streetaddress'];
$bldg = $_POST['bldg'];
$floor = $_POST['floor'];
$grandTotal = $_POST['grandtotal'];


$sql="INSERT INTO orders (order_date, client_firstname, client_lastname, client_phone, client_city, client_address, client_bldg, client_floor, grandtotal) 
VALUES  ('$orderdate', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$phone', '$city', '$address', '$bldg', '$floor', '$grandTotal');";
$r=$connect->prepare($sql);
$r->execute();
```

### inserting order items info (product id, product price...)

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $values){

    if(strpos($key, "pid") == true)
    {

        $sql="select * from products LEFT JOIN category on products.category_id = category.category_id where product_id = $_SESSION[$key]";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
            $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            $w = "weight";
            $w .= (string) $r['product_id'];
            $weight = $_SESSION[$w];
            $total = $r['product_price']*$weight;

        $orderItemSql ="INSERT INTO order_item (order_id, product_id, product_price, product_weight, total)
       VALUES ('1',''".$r['product_id']."', '".$r['product_price']."', '$weight','$grandTotal')";
        $g=$connect->prepare($orderItemSql);
        $g->execute();


    }

}

$order_id;
if($connect->query($sql) === true) {
   $order_id = $connect->insert_id;
   $valid['order_id'] = $order_id;  
}
```

$orderid is adding 2 numbers at once, how would this be solved?

and $orderItemSql is not functioning maybe this be because of $orderid?
I tried to insert instead $orderid a standard number in the statement but it still didn't work.
couldn't figure it out
your help will be appreciated in advance! thanks

Comment: You make a loop over you session values. But one thing i like to point out. Prepared statemenst don't work that way, your way is still vurnerable .  $orderItemSql ="INSERT INTO order_item (order_id, product_id, product_price, product_weight, total)
       VALUES (?,?, ?,?,Ä?)"; and the bind the variables is the correct way to use prepared statemenst. I don't think that they are your problem, but still

Comment: Last_insert_id tells you the last insert id; I'm not sure how it relates to the code presented here. And yes, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
$orderid = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
```